# Prove that if $f$ is uniformly continuous on a bounded set $S$, then $f$ is bounded on S

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Prove that if $f$ is uniformly continuous on a bounded set $S$, then $f$ is bounded on $S$.

Here's my proof. Can someone please verify it?

Suppose $f$ is not bounded on $S$. Then, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, there corresponds an $f(x_n)$ such that $|f(x_n)|>n$, where $x_n \in S$. Pick a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$. Then, $(x_{n_k})$ is cauchy. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $S$, this implies that $f(x_{n_k})$ is cauchy. However, this cannot be the case, since $f(x_{n_k})$ clearly diverges. Therefore, it must be the case that $f$ is bounded on $S$.

Comment: Is $S$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or something else?

Comment: $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Your proof is fine then.

Comment: Also the codomain $Y$ of $f:S\to Y$ is some normed vector space or similar such that the notation $|\cdot |$ in $|f(x_n)|$ makes sense, but I guess we have $Y=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If $S$ is not closed, there is no guarantee that $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence in $S$. The limit point may not be contained in $S$. So you should emphasize the convergent subsequence converges in the set's closure $\overline{E}$, which still implies the sequence is Cauchy.